# Chart.js and react-chartjs-2 property translate is missing type

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am facing an issue with this library, I am trying to render a simple vertical bar chart but it fails during the compilation because apparently it is missing the property translate.

I've been looking into the documentation and the source code but couldn't find anything related to it. Just an issue open on their git.

I tried downgrading but couldn't solve it.

Could someone please point me to the right direction? Thank you so much in advance

````
  labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun'],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Figures',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
      ],
      borderWidth: 1,
    },
  ],
};

const options = {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [
      {
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};

class SandBoxPage extends React.Component<PropsType> {

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div className={classes.div}>
              <div>
               <Bar data={data} options={options} />
              </div>
            )}
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}```

The error: 

```{
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "2741",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Property 'translate' is missing in type '{ data: { labels: string[]; datasets: { label: string; data: number[]; backgroundColor: string[]; borderColor: string[]; borderWidth: number; }[]; }; options: { scales: { yAxes: { ticks: { beginAtZero: boolean; translate: boolean; }; }[]; }; }; }' but required in type 'Pick<Props, \"data\" | \"className\" | \"style\" | \"title\" | \"defaultChecked\" | \"defaultValue\" | \"suppressContentEditableWarning\" | \"suppressHydrationWarning\" | \"accessKey\" | ... 254 more ... | \"getElementsAtEvent\">'.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 82,
    "startColumn": 17,
    "endLineNumber": 82,
    "endColumn": 20
}```
````

Comment: Is this your full code since you are not using any translate property, and chart.js also does not support it

Comment: Yes, it is.

I am not using any property called 'translate'

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out, in the end I am just downgrading the version of react-chartjs.

There are issues open related to that error on their git, in the mean time I think downgrading is a good opportunity.